# Infinite scroll doesn't work when scrolled all the way to the end of the div

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, chat, infinite-scroll

I am trying to make an infinite scroll in my chat. I'm using the scroll event to check if `scrolltop < clientHeight` and call a function `loadMore` if it is. This works pretty well as long as you never scroll to the very top. I made a gif to show this (hopefully it makes sense):

[image]

If you still have more room to scroll when the older messages get loaded, you keep your place and the scroll bar gets pushed down.

But if you are scrolled all the way to the top when the older messages get loaded, the scroll bar stays pinned to the top and you lose your place (also the scroll event stops being fired, so you stop loading messages unless you scroll down a little)

Has anyone else experienced this? And what did you do to fix it? Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the code that executed on the scroll event?

Comment: it is literally `if (scrollTop < clientHeight) { loadMoreMessages() }` @Y.Gherbi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated the answer to support 2 directions (up or down) and loading paddings. Please run the snippet in expanded mode, inline preview frame is too small for the scrollable list.

```js
var isLoadingAlready = false;
var upDirection = true; // to load records on top of the list; false to load them to the end of the list
var loadThreshold = 100; // distance to the edge (in pixels) to start loading
var howManyDataLoadsAvailable = 5;

if (upDirection){
    $('.scroll')[0].scrollTop = 100000; // scrolling all the way down
    $('.scroll').css('paddingTop', loadThreshold);
} else {
    $('.scroll').css('paddingBottom', loadThreshold);
}

$('.scroll').on('scroll', function () {
    var s = this; // picking DOM element

    if (s) { // just to be sure/safe
        var scrollableHeight = s.scrollHeight - s.clientHeight;
        if (scrollableHeight > 0) {
            var scrollTop = s.scrollTop;
            var distToTheEdge = upDirection?scrollTop:scrollableHeight - scrollTop;
            if (distToTheEdge < loadThreshold && !isLoadingAlready) {
                isLoadingAlready = true;
                loadMoreRecords(function () { // assuming you have a callback to allow next loading
                    isLoadingAlready = false;
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

loadMoreRecords();

function loadMoreRecords(doneCallback){
    $('.scroll').addClass('loading');

    // simulating the actual loading process with setTimeout
    setTimeout(function(){
        // simulated items to insert:
        var items = [];
        if (howManyDataLoadsAvailable-- > 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                items.push($('<li>').text('msg: '+(i+1)+', parts left: '+howManyDataLoadsAvailable));
            }
        }

        var $se = $('.scroll'); // scrollable DOM element
        var $ul = $('.scroll ul');
        var se = $se[0];
        if (upDirection) {
            var hBefore = $ul.height();
            $ul.prepend(items);
            var hDiff = $ul.height() - hBefore;
            se.scrollTop = Math.max(hDiff, loadThreshold);
        } else {
            $ul.append(items);
            se.scrollTop = se.scrollHeight - se.clientHeight - Math.max(se.scrollHeight - se.clientHeight - se.scrollTop, loadThreshold);
        }
        $se.removeClass('loading');
        if (typeof(doneCallback) === 'function'){
            doneCallback();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

```css
.scroll{
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed #aaa;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 1em;
}
.scroll.loading{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  animation: colorchange 1200ms;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}


@keyframes colorchange
{
  0%   {background: #def;}
  100% {background: white;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroll">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude you rock! The line that fixed it was `se.scrollTop = Math.max(hDiff, loadThreshold);` I'm not sure I understand why though.. can you please explain?

Comment: @EgorEgorov it's required to make sure that you don't violate the border that triggers the loading. So it would scroll to the last added item (using the height of all added items), but if it's closer than that border somehow (too few items or padding isn't enough) - you will be placed in "safe" place behind that border. I hope it makes sense )